# UML contracted user case contains system borders?

Tags: uml

Does contracted user case contain system borders? I mean: does it contain something like: machine doing biscuits, or just selling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- According to UML standard, every use case element MUST have at least one association with an actor element.
- So, if you want to show something as `border classes`, i.e., elements that are connected to user and elements that are not connected to user, it is impossible. EVERY use case shown in UC diagram must be connected to user.
- The UC diagram is not for showing *inner*, invisible for user behaviours. Its purpose is to define the `subject` <sub><sup>(according to UML standard, the product you are working at)</sup></sub>  by defining all its *external* behaviours.
- A system on UC diagram is shown as a rectangle. Its borders contain the use cases that belong to the system. The same for subsystems, components and packages on the UC diagram.
- So, a machine whose functionalities only support other machines, but never works with Actor (human or external system), is NOT a subsystem in UC diagram terms. Its functionality is not a use case. If you'll try to show it somehow here, you'll get a very bad and unreadable UC diagram. Show it on component and deployment diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

You have to depict the **relevant** use cases for each actor. So what are your actor(s) and does it make sense to associate them to "machine doing biscuit" or "selling" use cases?